# Kernel Panic When Starting Installer on HP DL360 G6

Tags: server, kernel

I can boot up to the USB, but after I select the language (with normal kernel or HWE kernel) on 16.04.5 server, I get this error. (this particular pic is with HWE kernel)

[image: error]

Comment: Try reseating DIMM 4 of CPU 0.  If that doesn't work, might be a bad RAM module.

Comment: The bios was complaining about some badd ram in DIMM 8 and DIMM 9 so I'll try that.